# Create chart in excel second sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I am writing a C# Interop code to create report in excel with chart in 2nd sheet.
I am able create chart, but it is coming in first sheet. Please help get the same in second sheet. My code is here.

```
Range chartRange;
Object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)sheet0.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 70, 250, 250);
Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
chartRange = sheet0.get_Range("G1", "H1");
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, XlRowCol.xlColumns);
chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xl3DLine;
```

Comment: where do you define/assign `sheet0`? You probably need to assign your second worksheet to `sheet0`...